# Maven project on new Kepler workspace fails with "Could not initialize class AspectJExpressionPointcut"

Tags: spring, maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-kepler

I have had a working Indigo workspace for quite a while, with many projects checked out from SVN.  Mostly Ant projects, but a few critical Maven projects.

I'm struggling to get a Kepler workspace working with the same projects.  I've essentially given up on the pure STS installation, as that gives me (different) errors in both Maven projects.  I filed both Eclipse and STS bugs, and they both say it's the others problem, so I've given up on that path for now.

I'm now trying to start with pure Eclipse and install the Spring pieces I want.  I thought I had all the plugins installed that I need, and I'm not getting the error dialogs that I was getting with the STS installation, but I'm getting a build error I can't handle.  It's saying this:

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for Could not initialize class org.springframework.ide.eclipse.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut
```

I suppose I'm missing some plugin, but I don't know what it would be.

I even did a somewhat exhaustive search for that class ("AspectJExpressionPointcut") in my workspace and Kepler distro, and it can't find it, unless it's in a jar file that's inside a jar file (my search just looks for classes in jar files in a directory tree).  I see references to it on the internet, but I can't get much out of those references.

Comment: Did you ultimately find a solution for this? Seems like I'm facing the exact same problem - my scenario is also remarkably similar to yours. (Relevant xkcd: http://xkcd.com/979/)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to install Spring IDE AJDT Integration. For Eclipse Kepler you need to add

`http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e4.3/`

to the list of update sites, then install "Spring IDE AJDT Integration"